# How to set the longitude and latitude values to other location from google map api?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, google-maps, google-api

Here is the google map jquery plugin code.

> jsfiddle.net/gUhHr/

In this jquery google map api code, I'm not able to find the latitude and longitude values.By default, it is displaying this image..[image]

I need to change the value to other location by setting latitude and longitude values.Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I am l'le Confused Why u wany to Add Lat and long with your Own

there is inbuilt Method that will do same for you.

getCurrentPosition();

use this method to get your Lat and long.

for More Details Do check:-

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp

Comment: there will be some IP conflict if I use geolocation

Comment: How? Can You Please Explain?